# neo4j remove labels , invalid input -

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

In the neo4j browser i try to execute the following command:

```
match(n:DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE) remove n:client-18d1b5fb-c7b5-4769-9b75-363ec596b012 return n
```

I get the following error:

```
    Invalid input '-': expected
  ","
  "CALL"
  "CREATE"
  "DELETE"
  "DETACH"
  "FOREACH"
  "LOAD"
  "MATCH"
  "MERGE"
  "OPTIONAL"
  "REMOVE"
  "RETURN"
  "SET"
  "UNION"
  "UNWIND"
  "USE"
  "WITH"
  <EOF> (line 1, column 44 (offset: 43))
"match(n:DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE) remove n:client-18d1b5fb-c7b5-4769-9b75-363ec596b012 return n"
```

Something is wrong with the use of "-" in the label, but cannot change it. How can i deal with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use back-ticks ` for the labels, like so,

```
match(n:DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE) remove n:`client-18d1b5fb-c7b5-4769-9b75-363ec596b012` return n
```